# Socket : 2 way communication in python

Tags: python, sockets

I want a two way communication in  Python :

I want to bind to a socket where one client can connect to, and then server and client can "chat" with eachother.

I already have the basic listener :

```
import socket
HOST='' #localhost
PORT=50008

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) #create an INET, STREAMing socket
s.bind((HOST,PORT)) #bind to that port
s.listen(1) #listen for user input and accept 1 connection at a time.

conn, addr = s.accept()

print "The connection has been set up"
bool=1
while bool==1:
        data=conn.recv(1024)
        print data
        if "#!END!#" in data:
                print "closing the connection"
                s.close()
                bool=0
```

What I want to do now is implement something so this script also accepts user input and after the enter key is hit, send it back to the client.

But I can't figure out how I can do this ? Because if  I would do it like this :

```
while bool==1:
    data=conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    u_input = raw_input("input now")
    if u_input != "":
       conn.send(u_input)
       u_input= ""
```

Problem is that it probably hangs at the user input prompt, so it does not allow my client to send data.

How do I solve this ?

I want to keep it in one window, can this be solved with threads ?

(I've never used threads in python)

Comment: (DOES NOT SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM) `bool` is a built-in type and you overwrite it, so maybe you want to use a different variable name. A nicer solution may be `while True` in combination with `break`.

Comment: Do you want to send every single character? Or the whole text?

Answer (score 5):

Python's sockets have a [makefile tool](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) to make this sort of interaction much easier.  After creating a socket *s*, then run `f = s.makefile()`.  That will return an object with a file-like interface (so you can use *readline*, *write*, *writelines* and other convenient method calls).  The Python standard library itself makes use of this approach (see the source for *[ftplib](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ftplib.py)* and *[poplib](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/poplib.py)* for example).

To get text from the client and display it on the server console, write a loop with `print f.readline()`.

To get text from the server console and send it to the client, write a loop with `f.write(raw_input('+ ') + '\n')`.

To be send and receive at the same time, do those two steps separate threads:

```
 Thread(target=read_client_and_print_to_console).start()
 Thread(target=read_server_console_and_send).start()
```

If you prefer async over threads, here are two examples to get you started:

- [Basic Async HTTP Client](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-http-client)
- [Basic Async Echo Server](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-echo-server)

Comment: Yea, but I still dont understand how I would  be able to ask for user input and write to the screen at the same time :(

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you have two sources of input you're waiting for: the socket and the user. The three main approaches I can think of are to use asynchronous I/O, to use synchronous (blocking) I/O with multiple threads, or to use synchronous I/O with timeouts. The last approach is conceptually the simplest: wait for data on the socket for up to some timeout period, then switch to waiting for the user to enter data to send, then back to the socket, etc.

I know at a lower level, you could implement this relatively easily by treating both the socket and stdin as I/O handles and use `select` to wait on both of them simultaneously, but I can't recall if that functionality is mapped into Python, or if so, how. That's potentially a very good way of handling this if you can make it work. EDIT: I looked it up, and Python does have a `select` module, but it sounds like it only functions like this under Unix operating systems--in Windows, it can only accept sockets, not stdin or files.

Comment: If Windows compatibility is a non-issue, then `select` would be my personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked twisted? [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) python event driven networking engine and library or 
[oidranot](https://github.com/marxus85/oidanrot) a python library especially for that based on torando web server