# Python - How to perform socket communication via socket.makefile?

Tags: python, sockets

Based on the highest-rated answer to this post:

[Socket : 2 way communication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248577/socket-2-way-communication-in-python)

And the docks:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#targetText=socket.makefile

I'm attempting to work out how to use `socket.makefile` to send/receive over a socket.  Here is what I have so far:

Server.py:

```
# Server.py

import socket

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'


def main():
    # instantiate a socket object
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('socket instantiated')

    # bind the socket
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print('socket binded')

    # start the socket listening
    sock.listen(10)
    print('socket now listening')

    # accept the socket response from the client, get the connection object
    conn, addr = sock.accept()              # Note: execution waits here until the client calls sock.connect()
    print('socket accepted, got connection object')

    sockFile = sock.makefile()

    while True:
        message = sockFile.readline()
        print('received: ' + str(message))
    # end while
# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client.py:

```
# Client.py

import socket
import time

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'


def main():
    # instantiate a socket object
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('socket instantiated')

    # connect the socket
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))    # Note: if execution gets here before the server starts up, this line will cause a crash
    print('socket connected')

    sockFile = sock.makefile(mode='w')

    myCounter = 0
    while True:
        message = 'message ' + str(myCounter)
        print('sending: ' + message)

        sockFile.write(message)

        myCounter += 1
        time.sleep(1)       # wait for 1 sec before sending next text message
    # end while
# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Right now if I start the server, then the client from separate command prompts, the client seems to be working:

Client.py output:

```
$ python3 Client.py 
socket instantiated
socket connected
sending: message 0
sending: message 1
sending: message 2
sending: message 3
sending: message 4
sending: message 5
```

But the server fails with the error:

```
$ python3 Server.py 
socket instantiated
socket binded
socket now listening
socket accepted, got connection object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Server.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "Server.py", line 32, in main
    message = sockFile.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

How can I connect the transport endpoint successfully on the server when using `socket.makefile`?  I'm not sure what the syntax is in this case.  I don't end up using `conn` and `addr` as I would on the server with the more traditional way of doing it, perhaps that's where I'm going wrong?

--- Edit ---

In `Server.py` I tried to use the `connection` with the `makefile()` function like so:

```
.
.
.
    # accept the socket response from the client, get the connection object
    conn, addr = sock.accept()              # Note: execution waits here until the client calls sock.connect()
    print('socket accepted, got connection object')

    connFile = conn.makefile()

    while True:
        message = connFile.readline()
        print('received: ' + str(message))
    # end while
.
.
.
```

But this does not work either, `Client.py` still works as before but now `Server.py` just hangs:

```
$ python3 Server.py 
socket instantiated
socket binded
socket now listening
socket accepted, got connection object
(hangs here forever)
```

--- Edit2 ---

Now I'm really confused.  Based on this post:

https://bugs.python.org/issue35928

I pretty much copied the posters code so Server.py now looks like this:

```
# Server.py

import socket

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'

def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))

        print(f'Waiting for connection on port {s.getsockname()[1]}')
        s.listen(1)

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(f'Connected by {addr}')

        with conn:
            f = conn.makefile(mode='rw')

            while True:
                print('before f.readline()')
                m = f.readline()
                print('after f.readline()')
                print(f'msg: {m!r}')

                if not m:
                    exit(0)

                f.write(m)
                f.flush()

# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And `Server.py` still hangs on the read!!

```
$ python3 Server.py 
Waiting for connection on port 65439
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 47536)
before f.readline()
```

According to the last post in the responses the poster's original concern is supposedly fixed so this should work now.  I'm still not sure how to accomplish this.

--- Edit3 ---

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.3` with the latest updates and `Python 3.6.9` if that matters

Answer (score 3):

In your server code:

```
conn, addr = sock.accept()
calls sock.connect()
sockFile = sock.makefile()

    while True:
        message = sockFile.readline()
```

You made a client socket (conn) but you never used it.
The client is writing so you should be reading from the client socket (conn)
Also I think you should call accept from inside the while loop.

```
while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        sockFile = conn.makefile()
        message = sockFile.readline()
```

Comment: This is the only post that had code for `sock.makefile()` that I could get to work. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Socket does not work this way.  It is supposed to complete one message and to be destroyed.  See "Socket Programming HOWTO" by Gordon McMillan on Python documentation page.  So you could organize your code like below.  This transmits one message and then shutdown/close.

```
#  server.py

import socket

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'


def main():
    # instantiate a socket object
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('socket instantiated')

    # bind the socket
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print('socket binded')

    # start the socket listening
    sock.listen(10)
    print('socket now listening')

    # accept the socket response from the client, get the connection object
    conn, addr = sock.accept()              # Note: execution waits here until the client calls sock.connect()
    print('socket accepted, got connection object')

    sockFile = conn.makefile()

    # while True:
    message = sockFile.readline()
    print('received: ' + str(message))
    
    # end while
# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and client code,

```
# client.py

import socket
import time

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'


def main():
    # instantiate a socket object
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('socket instantiated')

    # connect the socket
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))    # Note: if execution gets here before the server starts up, this line will cause a crash
    print('socket connected')

    sockFile = sock.makefile(mode='w')

    myCounter = 0
    # while True:

    message = 'message ' + str(myCounter) + '\r\n'
    print('sending: ' + message)

    sockFile.write(message)
    # sockFile.flush()
    sockFile.close()

    # myCounter += 1
    # time.sleep(1)       # wait for 1 sec before sending next text message
    # end while
# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you really want to transmit multiple messages in one script, create one new socket for each message.  See code below,

```
# server_multi.py

import socket

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'


def main():
    # instantiate a socket object
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('socket instantiated')

    # bind the socket
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print('socket binded')

    # start the socket listening
    sock.listen(10)
    print('socket now listening')

    while True:
        # accept the socket response from the client, get the connection object
        conn, addr = sock.accept()              # Note: execution waits here until the client calls sock.connect()
        print('socket accepted, got connection object')

        sockFile = conn.makefile()

        # while True:
        message = sockFile.readline()
        print('received: ' + str(message))

        conn.close()
    
    # end while
# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the client code looks like this,

```
# client_multi.py 

import socket
import time

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'text_received'


def main():
    # instantiate a socket object
    
    myCounter = 0

    while True:

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print('socket instantiated')

        # connect the socket
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))    # Note: if execution gets here before the server starts up, this line will cause a crash
        print('socket connected')

        sockFile = sock.makefile(mode='w')

        # while True:

        message = 'message ' + str(myCounter) + '\r\n'
        print('sending: ' + message)

        sockFile.write(message)
        # sockFile.flush()
        sockFile.close()

        myCounter += 1
        
        time.sleep(1)       # wait for 1 sec before sending next text message
    # end while
# end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Here's the snip from "Socket Programming HOWTO" by Gordon McMillan:  "When the connect completes, the socket s can be used to send in a request for the text of the page. The same socket will read the reply, and then be destroyed. That’s right, destroyed. Client sockets are normally only used for one exchange (or a small set of sequential exchanges)." Python sockets themselves are not single-use: ('... small set of sequential exchanges'), it's a style prescription of his. It's probably good practice, but sometimes you need long-open sockets, and Python presumably supports that use.

Comment: The "Socket Programming HOWTO" is both outdated and meant for people new to sockets. It's outdated because even HTTP can re-use the same socket for exchanging multiple messages (see [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)). And it's meant for newbies because it's from the viewpoint of HTTP. But HTTP is not the only protocol that uses sockets - many other protocols exist that re-use the same socket - and python's sockets are usable for them too.